# Algolia - Places autocomplete using php api client

Tags: algolia

I've been playing around with the Algolia autocomplete places.js library. When you use the library you get a list of suggestions e.g.

```
{
  "query": "pari",
  "suggestion": {
     "name": "Paris",
     "administrative": "Île-de-France",
     "country": "France",
     "countryCode": "fr",
     "type": "city",
     "latlng": {
     "lat": 48.8546,
     "lng": 2.34771
   },
  "postcode": "75000",
  "highlight": {
      "name": "<em>Pari</em>s",
      "administrative": "Île-de-France",
      "country": "France"
   },
   "value": "Paris, Île-de-France, France"
 }
}
```

I have a need to use the php client and return a list of suggestions for my own applications api e.g.

```
$places = \AlgoliaSearch\Client::initPlaces();

$result = $places->search($term, [

        'type' => ['city', 'country', 'address'],
        'language' => 'en',
        'aroundLatLngViaIP' => false,

]);

dd($result);
```

However when you use the php client (note I'm using laravel scout in this instance) you don't get a list of suggestions i.e. there is no `value` property (Full display name of the place found)in the response that you can return back to the end user - instead you end up with the following response?

```
 {
   "hits": [{
   "objectID": "145746683_7444",
      "locale_names": {
         "default": ["Paris"],
    },
   "city": {
       "default": ["Paris"],
    },
   "county": {
       "default": ["Paris"],
   },
   "administrative": ["Île-de-France"],
   "country": {
       "default": "France",
   },
   "country_code": "fr",
   "postcode": ["75000"],
   "population": 2243833,
   "_geoloc": {
       "lat": 48.8564,
       "lng": 2.3521
   },
   "_highlightResult": {
       "locale_names": {
          "default": [{
              "value": "<em>Paris</em>",
              "fullyHighlighted": true,
              "matchedWords": ["paris"],
              "matchLevel": "full"
          }]
     },

   }
 }],
 "nbHits": 1,
 "query": "Paris"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Algolia Places JavaScript library](https://github.com/algolia/places/blob/master/src/formatHit.js#L76-L139), this is the data they're dealing with as well before it is given down to the Autocomplete:

```js
    const name = hit.locale_names[0];
    const country = hit.country;
    const administrative =
      hit.administrative && hit.administrative[0] !== name
        ? hit.administrative[0]
        : undefined;
    const city = hit.city && hit.city[0] !== name ? hit.city[0] : undefined;
    const suburb =
      hit.suburb && hit.suburb[0] !== name ? hit.suburb[0] : undefined;

    const county =
      hit.county && hit.county[0] !== name ? hit.county[0] : undefined;

    const { postcode, highlightedPostcode } =
      hit.postcode && hit.postcode.length
        ? getBestPostcode(hit.postcode, hit._highlightResult.postcode)
        : { postcode: undefined, highlightedPostcode: undefined };

    const highlight = {
      name: getBestHighlightedForm(hit._highlightResult.locale_names),
      city: city
        ? getBestHighlightedForm(hit._highlightResult.city)
        : undefined,
      administrative: administrative
        ? getBestHighlightedForm(hit._highlightResult.administrative)
        : undefined,
      country: country ? hit._highlightResult.country.value : undefined,
      suburb: suburb
        ? getBestHighlightedForm(hit._highlightResult.suburb)
        : undefined,
      county: county
        ? getBestHighlightedForm(hit._highlightResult.county)
        : undefined,
      postcode: highlightedPostcode,
    };

    const suggestion = {
      name,
      administrative,
      county,
      city,
      suburb,
      country,
      countryCode: findCountryCode(hit._tags),
      type: findType(hit._tags),
      latlng: {
        lat: hit._geoloc.lat,
        lng: hit._geoloc.lng,
      },
      postcode,
      postcodes: hit.postcode && hit.postcode.length ? hit.postcode : undefined,
    };

    // this is the value to put inside the <input value=
    const value = formatInputValue(suggestion);
```

You should find all you need in this code, and more specifically for the full display name of the found place, it is built from this (where `suggestion` from the code above is the rendering context for the code below):

```
 const out = `${name}${type !== 'country' && country !== undefined ? ',' : ''}
 ${city ? `${city},` : ''}
 ${administrative ? `${administrative},` : ''}
 ${country ? country : ''}`
    .replace(/\s*\n\s*/g, ' ')
    .trim();
  return out;
```

(found in the [`formatInputValue.js file`](https://github.com/algolia/places/blob/master/src/formatInputValue.js)`)

Comment: This does not answer the question and is best stated in the comment section. The variables used in the formatInputValue.js file do not make use of the same array structure returned by the PHP client

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno it *does* answer the question if you take the time to look at the code I linked to first. You would then realize that the data dealt with in formatInputValue.js is derived from exactly what the OP posted in his question. I updated my answer to include the full code so that it's more standalone.

Comment: My issue is the question posted is in PHP and your solution is in JS. I'll try to convert the code into PHP and see if it works.

Comment: The OP quoted more JSON code than PHP, and as it turns out, the relevant pieces of code from Algolia's libs that answer the question are in JS. The issue and the question aren't PHP-specific, but "how do I manipulate the data returned by the client", and that's exactly what I'm showing :)